# Revoked visa and given a 5 year ban

Tags: usa, united-kingdom, visa, working-visas, immigration

[image]

Last year I had been granted a visa to travel to America, once I arrived in America I was stopped at immigration. I had my visa revoked and was given a 5 year ban for America. I want to know if this will affect my chances of obtaining a UK working visa. Also I know when applying for visa’s that one question is if I have ever been refused a visa, in this circumstance I am unsure of what answer to put as my visa was revoked. Is this the same as been refused a visa?

Comment: This will certainly cause UK officials to scrutinize any visa application you submit more thoroughly than they otherwise would.  A revocation is presumably distinct from a refusal.  Do they not ask you whether you've ever been refused admission anywhere?  That would be the obvious place to report this.

Comment: Whoever wrote that letter could use a course in proper English. Just saying.

Answer (score 10):

On UK visa forms you can expect to see [this wording](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/299663/VAF9-Personal_Details.pdf):

> 6.3 Have you ever been refused a visa for any country
>   including the UK?
>
> 6.7 Have you ever been deported, removed or otherwise
>   required to leave any country, including the UK?

As you can see, they ask both about being refused the visa before arrival, and being removed/deported upon or after arrival. Your case would be the second. There is room for additional information as well.

Leaving it off is not even a consideration - the UK and US share information and they would certainly spot it. Your visa would be summarily rejected, putting you in a worse situation than before.

It will of course have a negative effect on your application - they will question whether you will abide by the rules of your UK visa when you didn't abide by the rules of your US visa. The rest of your application would have to be *spotless*.